# Gwt template file of panel

Tags: gwt, user-interface, panel

I am a new GWT developer, just do some coding practice on the MVP framework of GWT, I encounter a interesting problem with the ui template file,

WHen I use HtmlPanel as the root element for widgets in the template, everything show up after module is loaded.

this template works as expected, however if I remove the  tag, using an absolutePanel instead nothing shows up, 
can anyone tell what could cause the problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you set the size of the AbsolutePanel?